# IE7: "Script is running slowly, do you want to stop it?" - How can I figure out which script it is?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

The damn thing gives me NO other information. It does not occur in any other browser.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all scripts run slowly in IE7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by an unbounded loop of some sort.

Culprits could be: for, setTimeout, do and while.

How large is this collection of scripts?  You could try the script debugging/profiling in IE8 while running in IE7 compatibility mode.

If that doesn't work, sometimes the old, remove x to isolate y works, albeit slowly.

Comment: I think that `setTimeout` is more likely to be the solution than the culprit. The message appears because a JS method runs too long without returning control back to the browser. `setTimeout` returns control to the browser, and could be used to break up a large/expensive loop into smaller parts that finish before IE7 puts up this message.

Comment: Yup, that's what usually does it. Nicholas C Zakas has a few suggestions in his [Speed up JavaScript](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/) articles

Comment: @Joel well, that article is a much more complete answer than mine. If you respond with your own answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: That was James that linked the article - I can't take credit for that.

Comment: I finally found it after clicking randomly in IE7 when it threw the pop-up it eventually gave me an actual error pop-up that showed me the script. The problem is a TON of jQuery .unbind() calls and various bindings when there are a ton of certain objects on the page. I will need to optimize that. If I click 'keep running the script' it eventually stops. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dynatrace ajax edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) to profile you javascript. That will tell you exactly what is using too much cpu time, no need to guess :)

Comment: You are welcome - it will probably be quite an eyeopener if you haven't used it before... it will tell you just about everything about everything that is using cpu time inside ie, including rendering and painting events... it is simply the best tool for the job and leaves firebug in the dirt ;) Too bad it only supports ie so far